# PHP level and experience system

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a levelling and experience system. I've done it but I'm trying to get PHP to work out how much experience is needed to level up.

For every level, an user needs 670 experience. But if I added 670 to their experience total, it wouldn't work it out correctly.

This is how I did it..

```
<?php $exp = ($user["experience"]+670); ?>
```

But that isn't working how much the user needs. Hope I've explained clearly. Any help will be nice, thanks.

Comment: If every level always requires 670 experience, it sounds like you want to find out how many are needed until the next multiple of 670. Have you thought about using the % operator in PHP?

Comment: I don't really know operators, so not really.

Comment: Define "isn't working." What is the expected behavior and what is the observed behavior?

Comment: Ah, OK. It's used for giving the remainder when dividing (it's known as the modulus operator). E.g. `25 % 6` would return `1`.

Comment: David. If an user has 678 experience, I'm trying to find out how much experience they need until they next level up. It would be 662. But I can't work out how to do this in PHP.

Comment: As marnir noted, you're looking for [the modulus operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about something along these lines:

The expression `$user["experience"] % 670` would give you the amount *over* from the last level. So if I had 671 experience, it would give 1, if I had 1360 experience, it would give 20, etc. Then you can subtract this amount from 670 to give the amount left.

(Also, as a general tip, it's helpful when coding if you have a so-called 'magic number' like 670, you could give it a name by defining a constant called e.g. EXP_PER_LEVEL, rather than using the bare value 670, so that if anyone's reading your code in future, they can easily work out what the 670 means, and also, if the amount of exp per level ever changes, you only have to change the value in one place, i.e. the place where the EXP_PER_LEVEL constant is defined)

Answer (score 3):

Okay, this is how I did my leveling system.. Mine's a little more advanced with skill points added..

```
<?php
$level_up = ($level + 1);
if ($exp >= $max_exp)
{
    $sql = "UPDATE   users 
            SET      level = (level + 1)
                     ,max_exp = (exp * 1.05)
                     ,skill_points = (skill_points + 3) 
            WHERE    id = '".$id."'
            LIMIT    1";
    $res = mysql_query($sql);
    if ($exp >= $max_exp)
    {
        echo      '<div class="Leveled">'
                . 'You sucessfully leveled up to '
                . $level_up . '!'
                . ' As a reward you were given 3 skill points!'
                . '</div>';
    }
    else
    {
    } 
}?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://www.daftspunk.com/code/php-experience-points-xp-level-system.html

It will calculate the current level and percentage to the next level. You set the distance for level 1 and it multiplies the amount for each subsequent level, eg:

Multiplier of 6x

Level 1 - 1XP  to 10XP

Level 2 - 10XP to 60XP

Level 3 - 60XP to 360XP

Level 4 - 360XP to 2160XP

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
 $exp = ($user["experience"] >= 670); // checking if the experience is higher
```

Or

```
 $user["experience"] += 670; // Adding 670 to the experience in the  $user array
```